# Nginx not serving up Django admin static files

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

An example 404 URL:

`http://ip.address/static/admin/css/base.css`

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Here's the associated files:

settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  '/home/username/sitename/sitenameenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static',
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/sitename/website/staticroot/'
```

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://ip.address/;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/username/sitename/website/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/username/sitename/sitename.sock;
    }
}
```

The regular static files are being served up correctly, and they were doing so also before I added `STATIC_ROOT` and used `collectstatic`, which I didn't think was necessary. My admin is getting 404s for its static files though.

Comment: Can you post a `404` url?

Comment: @xyres Question updated.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the answer with a better solution. Please take a look. I'd like to apologise for posting a crap answer in haste previously.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Running `collectstatic` will collect all your files in the directory specified by `STATIC_ROOT` settings.

So, you'll need to configure your Nginx server to serve your `STATIC_ROOT` folder at the `/satic/` url:

```
location /static/ {
    # using `alias` instead of `root`
    # vvv
    alias   /home/username/sitename/website/staticroot/;
            #                                  ^^^
            # the full path to the STATIC_ROOT directory
}
```

---

**Old Version (not very useful):**

**Why is this happening?**

Here's one important thing to note: Django doesn't serve static files. I'm sure you know that.

So, when your browser requests for an admin css file from -  `http://ip.address/static/admin/css/base.css`, this request is intercepted by your Nginx server because you've mapped `/static/` path to this directory - `/home/username/sitename/website/static/`.

Now, what happens next is, Nginx will try to find `/admin/css/base.css` file inside `/home/username/sitename/website/static/`. But there isn't any `admin` directory in there, hence this request ends up as a `404`.

---

**How to fix this?**

You can map `/static/admin/` url to that directory where the `admin` directory actually is. Example:

```
# put this before `location /static/` conf

location /static/admin/ {
    root   /home/username/sitename/sitenameenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/;
}
```

Comment: Does the location of `/static/admin/` matter inside my nginx config? Before `/static/`?

Comment: @smilebomb I'm not sure. I haven't tested it, so can't say.

Comment: This is not the right solution. The point of collectstatic is to collect all the static files in one place.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought about that, but I looked at the Nginx conf and this way seemed obvious. But I guess you're right. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated the answer. Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The way I understand the updated answer is that when I make CSS or JS changes to my project I'll have to run collectstatic every time to put the new files in staticroot. With the old answer, I don't have to to do this. Do I understand correctly? Why is that bad?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My nginx server on Centos 7.6 can't access to static folder in path `/home/user/app/mysyte/static/`. In `/var/log/nginx/error.log` same error

```
open() "/home/user/app/mysyte/static/*.css" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

For solving and understanding this problem `:=*`

1. run command `getenforce`
2. if enforcing - `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx`

for me string with errrors looks like

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1558033633.723:201): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=564f710dd55d a1=800 a2=0 a3=68632f656d6f682f items=0 ppid=7757 pid=7758 auid=4294967295 uid=998 gid=996 euid=998 suid=998 fsuid=998 egid=996 sgid=996 fsgid=996 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/nginx" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

copy id of audit msg `1558033633.723:201`

3. run command `grep yours_audit_id /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why`

output for me

```
[root@uwsgi ~]# grep 1558034479.384:221 /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
type=AVC msg=audit(1558034479.384:221): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=7758 comm="nginx" name="responsive.css" dev="dm-0" ino=17312394 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

        Was caused by:
        The boolean httpd_read_user_content was set incorrectly.
        Description:
        Allow httpd to read user content

        Allow access by executing:
        # setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

So as you can see answer here `setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1` when you run this command you see your static content